# Técnicas de SEO + utilizadas atualmente!

Tags: html, google, seo

Estive fazendo algumas pesquisas em alguns cursos sobre SEO, pois acredito que é um assunto muito promissor no campo da Internet mas muitas coisas ainda são um mistério para mim e talvez vocês possam me ajudar a clarear minha visão.

Vi vários sites na internet que nem aparecem Keywords nas MetasTag e ainda sim tem melhor posicionamento do que meu site, tento sempre utilizar as ALT dentro das Imagens, `<h1>` com conteúdos chaves da página e também uso o Link Building usando palavras chaves.

Alguém poderia me mandar falar quais são as principais coisas que influenciam em um SEO de uma página?

Agradeço se mandar um material para estudos que ache que ajude, acredito que o SEO é uma técnica muito importante mas que precisa ser usada da maneira correta para dar resultado, e é isso que estou tentando.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seguem minhas dicas.

Primeiro muita gente acha que SEO acontece só dentro da página, mas se no site do Google ou da Globo tiver um link apontando pro seu site pode ser muito mais relevante que qualquer outra coisa.

Então estude bastante SEO Off-Page, comesse lendo isso e depois se quiser leia o resto do conteúdo que é bem interessante.

http://www.seomaster.com.br/curso-tutorial-seo-gratis/offpage-seo

Agora uma dica para SEO On-Page. O Google está valorizando cada vez mais sites que tenham uma boa Acessibilidade. Portanto estude bastante a documentação WAI-ARIA e WCAG

https://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria

https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/aria

Outro fator MUITO importante é ter uma boa performance e um site "**mobile friendly**"! Vc pode usar essa ferramenta para avaliar se o seu site é bem aceito pelo Google ou não.

Notícia de 2017!
**Google Mobile First Index: Page Speed Included as a Ranking Factor**
http://www.thesempost.com/google-mobile-first-index-page-speed-ranking/

Pagina para vc testar a performance do seu site
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Resumindo o que eu vi de novo nos últimos tempos em SEO para o Google seria:

- Resposividade
- Performance
- Acessibilidade

TUDO isso pode influencia bastante no seu rankeamento, muito mais que as meta tags!

Outra coisa. Use as ferramentas do Google. Adicione Google Analitycs, registre a URL, Coloque um Site Map e construa um bom Robots.TXT
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/

https://analytics.google.com

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=pt-BR (sobre o site map)

**Protocolo HTTPS como fator de ranqueamento**

Outra notícia de 2017, mas que já se fala a algum tempo...
https://www.sangfroidwebdesign.com/search-engine-optimization-seo/google-https-ranking/

O Google vai dar preferencia para **sites seguros** ou seja, se o seu site for **HTTPS** pode ter um melhor resultado nas buscas, pois os sites **HTTP** serão classificados como *"não seguros"* 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**IMPORTANTE!**

Preste bastante atenção nas regras de PUNIÇÃO do Google!

Por exemplo, evite o uso abusivo de notificações, tipo essas janelinhas que agora aparecem em qualquer site!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Evite também bloquear seu conteúdo com Pop-ups como nessa imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Esses são fatores que o Google pode usar para diminuir seu rank!*

[]´s

Answer (score 4):

A algum tempo escrevi um pequeno manual sobre isso, vou deixar alguns trechos importantes como resposta e linkar o PDF ao final.

---

**Princípios de SEO**

*Spiders, Bots & Crawlers (São os robôs)*

Os robôs são programas que servem para analisar e indexar o conteúdo da sua
página nos motores de busca.

- Eles fazem uma ‘cópia’ do site. Para isso o site precisa ser legível (Muitas imagens prejudicam a indexação, navegação por Javascript ou Flash, nunca usar Flash).
- Novos sites precisam de links (Quanto mais links tiver para ou site através de Blogs, Redes Sociais, Sites Institucionais e etc, mais os robôs vão visitar o site para atualizar o
  conteúdo).

*HTML*

Conheça pelo menos os princípios básicos de HTML (É muito importante!!!).

Como estruturar uma página com tags de Título, Subtítulo, Descrição do
produto, Legendas, negrito, itálico, etc.
Faça um teste rápido para ver se sua loja é indexada. Escrevendo no google
“site:www.exemplo.com.br”.

*Pesquisa por palavra-chave (Keyword Research)*

A pesquisa por palavra-chave(Keyword) é a base para melhorar o
posicionamento. Utilize palavras claras para descrever o site e os produtos. As
palavras-chave são a base. Selecione as palavras certas utilizando ferramentas de pesquisa como Google Adwords e Google Trends. Não use palavras que apenas sua empresa conhece, ou seja, termos técnicos que seus clientes não utilizam ou não sabem.(in-house)
Importante: As pessoas não buscam da mesma maneira, e sempre haverá variações
nas buscas. Conteúdo original e exclusivo ganha melhor rankeamento. Não utilize a descrição do produto fornecido pelo fabricante crie a sua.

---

**Métodos de Otimização**

*On Page*
On Page é a parte da otimização que devemos dar mais importância, apesar de
ser muito necessária, não é tudo. Elementos Onpage a serem observados e otimizados:

**Title – Head Tags – Meta tags – URL**

**Title** - Uma das partes mais importante do On Page. O Google Webmasters Tools disponibiliza uma análise completa e de extrema importância que inclui títulos duplicados e outros fatores que podem atrapalhar. O primeiro passo para otimizar o site é otimizar o título e com um título diferente para cada página.

**Head Tags** - São os famosos h1, h2... até o h6, que para nós parece ser apenas uma organização visual, mas para os robôs é uma organização de conteúdo e nível de importância de cada sub-título.

**Meta Description** - É onde você vai escrever sobre aquela página, uma espécie de resumo do que o usuário vai encontrar na página. Assim como as Head Tags, não podem ser duplicadas, cada página com a sua Meta Description. Outra questão de extrema importância nessa tag, é que ela não pode passar de 160 caracteres. Pode chegar o mais próximo possível, de preferência que seja de 160 caracteres exatos, mas não pode passar. Essa é a descrição que vai aparecer abaixo do título do site no resultado de busca orgânica do Google e o que passar de 160 não será exibido.

**URL** - A URL deve conter o menor número de caracteres possíveis, o menor número de separadores e ainda ter muita informação, sem dúvidas é mais fácil do que parece. É muioto importante também, que a URL tenha separadores em forma de hífen (-) e não de underscore ou underline como é conhecida (_), pois os robôs  não consideram underscores como separadores de palavras.

---

**Off Page**

Ao contrário página On SEO, SEO fora da página refere-se a atividades fora dos
limites da página. Os mais importantes são:

**Link Building** - O Link Building é o mais popular método de SEO off-Page.
Basicamente é feito através da construção de links externos para o seu site, você deve reunir o maior número de apontamentos para o site, assim você pode ignorar seus concorrentes com classificação mais elevada. Por exemplo, se alguém gosta de um artigo e o referencia em outro lugar, isso é como dizer os motores de busca que esta página tem boas informações e que podem ser úteis para futuros usuários.(Mas muito cuidado com a qualidade dos links apontados)

**Social Media** - A mídia social é parte importante de SEO Off Page e se você
pensar sobre isso, é também uma forma de link building. Note que quase todos os links que você começa a partir de sites de mídia social são "nofollow", mas isso não significa que eles não têm qualquer valor.

**Social Bookmarking** - Bookmarking social não é tão popular como costumava
ser no passado, mas ainda é uma boa maneira de obter tráfego para o site. Dependendo do nicho você pode encontrar sites como reddit.com, digg.com, stumbleupon.com, scoop.it e delicious.com (para citar alguns) para promover o 
conteúdo. No Brasil ele não é muito comum, porém não deixa de ser uma  alternativa.

---

**Autoridade do Domínio**

A Autoridade do Domínio em SEO é justamente uma métrica que avalia uma série de fatores Off Page do domínio como um todo que atribui a ele maior ou menor relevância em relação a outros sites presentes nos bancos de dados dos grandes buscadores, como Google, por exemplo. Fatores que podem decisivos neste cálculo de autoridade de domínio:

**Idade do domínio, Reputação do site, Links que apontam para o site, Qualidade dos Inbound Links, Diversidade de links, Padrão temporal, Análise distributiva.**

Não é nada fácil manipular um indicador desses e na verdade é bem mais fácil seguir as boas práticas de SEO do que ficar perdendo tempo com esse tipo de manipulação. A autoridade do site vem naturalmente com a publicação de conteúdo de qualidade e uma estratégia de Link Building bem distribuída e calibrada.

> [Link para o arquivo do Manual](http://hinno.com.br/Manual_de_SEO_1.2.pdf)